# special characters in google app-engine task queue task names

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

Are dashes(-) or any other special characters allowed in task names in task queues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use dashes.  You can also have letters (any case) or numbers.  The name must be between 1 and 500 characters.

This is all from looking at the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/labs/taskqueue/taskqueue.py), which specifies that task names must match this regular expression:

```
MAX_TASK_NAME_LENGTH = 500
r'^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,%s}$' % MAX_TASK_NAME_LENGTH
```

Comment: I need to use a base64 encoded string as the task name but cannot because of this limitation on the name. Please star this issue that I filed if you are also looking for more flexibility in the task name  - https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12179&thanks=12179&ts=1437914891